# pandas from mac ports ImportError: No module named io.data

Tags: python, macos, pandas, macports

I installed pandas on osx 10.9.1 from mac ports via `sudo port install py27-pandas`.

On trying to run a simple example

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime

goog = DataReader("GOOG",  "yahoo", datetime(2000,1,1), datetime(2012,1,1))
print goog["Adj Close"]
```

When invoking python in a new terminal window, I get the following error

```
$ python2.7 pandas.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.data import DataReader
  File "/Users/adm/Documents/Factor/research/pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.data import DataReader
ImportError: No module named io.data
```

Also other `pandas` modules aren't being imported properly

```
    from pandas.stats.moments import rolling_std
ImportError: No module named stats.moments
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or if this is a bug in `macports` or `pandas` or `osx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a file named `pandas.py` in your current directory. Python is importing that one. Please rename it, so that the correct `pandas` module can be loaded.

By the way if you have problems installing pandas on Mac I recommend you use the [Anaconda](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda) distribution instead of Macports.